# How can I execute a shell script without exit? (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, terminal, shell-script, exit

I'm making a shortcut icon on my Dock which opens a terminal window with some preconfigured environment variables. I made a script and dragged it into my Dock. It runs well, however it exits immediately when it completed. I want to start console work with preconfigured variables. How can I make it does not exit after script execution complete?

Comment: Could you show your script?  The obvious ways I tried leave the terminal running.

Comment: @geekosaur The user probably uses an executable `.command` or `.tool` file. Opening such a file translates to a Terminal command of the form `/path/to/filename.command ; exit;`.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, the question is whether there is a way to counter it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put

`read -p "Press Return to Close..."`

as the last line of the script. That will keep it up until you hit enter.

**Re: your edit**

If you invoke `bash` (or whatever shell you use) as the last line of the script it should (as in does for me on Linux) stay open with a prompt.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for my question was unclear. I was wanted to start console work at the point.

Comment: @Eonil, I edited my answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: it works, but it launches a new shell instead of remaining opened shell. Preconfigured environment variables are disappeared.

Comment: @Eonil I tested it using `export FOO="Hello World"; bash` as script, then typed `echo $FOO` and it showed up. Alternatively, create a bash-script ad-hoc in your script and use it as `bash --init-file` to define your environment.